# Does Paypal need to review my iOS app before i release it to the App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

Ive just finished an app that has PayPal integrated, however while some of PayPals documentation states that Paypal needs to review the app I've read elsewhere that they have now changed it so you can just release it with the live credentials. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

If you are using the [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) or the [PayPal MPL library](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/), then no, you do not need to have PayPal review your app.

Comment: Is that true even when I do preapprovals? I can only get REST credentials, for MPL it takes me to www.paypal-apps.com where I can apply for live credentials, which sounds like a review process...

Comment: @webjunkie Yes, for preapprovals you need to fill out the application at www.paypal-apps.com. This will be reviewed and then approved/denied based on the information that you provide. If you are approved, you will then be able to use your Live credentials as the proper permissions will be given to your account.